# vi, find line and output/output to separate file

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a command in VI/VIM to search for particular text in the file and grab the whole line and output in either on the screen or separate file.  e.g.

```
This is some line with this _word_ and some other text.
This is some line with this some other text and some other text.
```

so this would output only the first line..

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just use grep?

Comment: `grep word filename`

What you're asking for is *exactly* what grep does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:redir > output.txt
:g/_word_/p
:redir END
```

The line will be output to the screen and to `output.txt`.  See `:h :redir`.

EDIT: I agree with others who suggest using plain old *nix `grep` if you can.  Situations where you might not be able to use `grep`:

- You're searching buffer text that doesn't exist in a file on the filesystem.
- You're using Vim-specific regex extensions, like cursor location, column number, marks, etc.
- You want do this in a cross-platform way, and `grep` might not exist on the system you're using.

`redir` can be useful in these situations.

Comment: Btw. do you know how to redir to C:\somepath\ under cygwin?

Comment: Something like `/cygdrive/c/somepath`.

Answer (score 1):

use the g (global) command:

```
:g/_word_/y
```

will yank all lines containing `_word_`

---

having mentioned the DOS `find` command, you probably want to use `grep`:

```
grep -h '_word_' * > results
```

Comment: i bow to your superior vi mastery

Answer (score 0):

in vi, from command mode

search for `_word_`

```
 /_word_
```

yank the line

```
yy
```

paste the line

```
p
```

Comment: well, I have several thousands of lines, I wanted to do it in a more streamlined fashion. similar to DOS command: find /i "String" "c:\my src\myfile.txt"

Comment: then use grep as the original commenter suggested